# Split weeks between two date range

Tags: php, date, datetime, split

Split week by week from two date range.

ex:

Starting date : 2015-01-11

Ending date : 2015-01-31

need this format :

Week 1:

```
Array ( [0] => 2015-01-11 [1] => 2015-01-12 [2] => 2015-01-13 [3] => 15-01-14 [4] => 2015-01-15 [5] => 2015-01-16 [6] => 2015-01-17
```

Week 2:

```
Array([0] => 2015-01-18 [1] => 2015-01-19 [2] => 2015-01-20 [3] => 2015-01-21 [4] => 2015-01-22 [5] => 2015-01-23 [6] => 2015-01-24)
```

Week 3:

```
Array([0] => 2015-01-25 [1] => 2015-01-26 [2] => 2015-01-27 [3] => 2015-01-28 [4] => 2015-01-29 [5] => 2015-01-30 [6] => 2015-01-31)
```

Thanks to advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: Hello Jay Blanchard, select start date and end date from datepickter and split weeks from those dates range. Display row by row(weeks).

Comment: foreach ($week as $day) {
   $dates [] = $day['date'];
  }

Comment: Post that in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like that works for you ?

```
<?php
 // Set timezone
 date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

 // Start date
 $date = '2015-01-11';
 // End date
 $end_date = '2015-01-31';
 $array_final = array();
 $array  = array();
 $i=0;
 while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
     if($i%6==0 && $i>0){
         array_push($array_final,$array);   
         $array  = array();
     }

    array_push($array,$date);    

    $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
    $i++;
}
print_r($array_final);
?>
```

its returning an array with a row for each week.
each weak row is returning what you want : an array from 0 to 6 with the date in it.

You can try it on [phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/)

Array (

[0] => Array ( [0] => 2015-01-11 [1] => 2015-01-12 [2] => 2015-01-13 [3] => 2015-01-14 [4] => 2015-01-15 [5] => 2015-01-16 )

[1] => Array ( [0] => 2015-01-17 [1] => 2015-01-18 [2] => 2015-01-19 [3] => 2015-01-20 [4] => 2015-01-21 [5] => 2015-01-22 )

[2] => Array ( [0] => 2015-01-23 [1] => 2015-01-24 [2] => 2015-01-25 [3] => 2015-01-26 [4] => 2015-01-27 [5] => 2015-01-28 ) )

Comment: need this concept... thanks Romain Derie.

Comment: change the 2 dates in  
// Start date
 $date = '2019-02-01';
 // End date
 $end_date = '2019-02-28';
And it will fail, shame